# Converting a string to lower-case (without built-in to-lower functions!)

Tags: code-golf, printable-ascii

The goal of this code-golf is to create a code that lets the user input an ASCII string (contains only [printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)), and your program outputs the lower-case variant of this string.

**Important: you are NOT allowed to use a built-in function that converts the string (or just one character) to lowercase (such as `ToLower()` in .NET, `strtolower()` in PHP
, ...)!** You're allowed to use all other built-in functions, however.

**Another important note:** The input string doesn't contain *only* uppercase characters. The input string is a mix of uppercase characters, lowercase characters, numbers and other [ASCII printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) characters.

Good luck!

Comment: unfortunately, I'll have to opt-out. I'm not a beginner.

Comment: @Jan: Well, with beginner I actually meant that the skill level of this would be 'beginner', not that only beginners would be allowed to enter. I removed the word 'beginner' and surely, you're allowed to enter.

Comment: Are regular expressions allowed? Only GolfScript could beat `s/./\L\0/g`.

Comment: @manatwork: surely `\L` is built in?

Comment: @manatwork: Yes, a regex is allowed.

Comment: @marinus is builtin, but not a function. (This would be a function in the regular expression: `s/./lc$&/ge`, so this one clearly not allowed.)

Comment: @ProgramFOX, can we assume the input will contain only uppercase letters and no other characters?

Comment: @manatwork: No, the input will contain uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and some other ASCII characters.

Comment: May the input string contain control characters such as tab, line break, carriage return, or is only the range of [ASCII printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) valid input? What about null bytes, do they have to be replicated in the output?

Comment: @FireFly: Only printable characters. I didn't mention that in the question, so it's updated now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Shell - 10

Translation of @Gowtham's Perl solution using `/bin/tr`.

```
tr A-Z a-z
```

Sample run:

```
% tr A-Z a-z <<<'Hello WORLD! @'
hello world! @
```

Comment: What makes this the accepted answer, out of curiosity? Gowtham had a 10-character solution first…

Comment: Based on [the discussion on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/674/what-to-do-if-therere-two-answers-with-the-shortest-code) it seems the reasoning is that Gowtham's solution is 11 chars (because the `-p` flag counts as one).  I agree though, his seems like it deserves more to be accepted..

Comment: Ah, thanks – that makes sense. I’ll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 57):

## Python 2.7 - 30 (with terrible and unapologetic rule abuse)

```
raw_input().upper().swapcase()
```

As an anonymous edit pointed out, you can do it in **<del>27</del> 26 in Python 3**:

```
input().upper().swapcase()
```

I'm flagrantly abusing the rules here, but...

> **Important: you are NOT allowed to use a built-in function that converts the string (or just one character) to lowercase (such as `ToLower()` in .NET, `strtolower()` in PHP 
>   , ...)!** You're allowed to use all other built-in functions, however.

This **takes the strings and coverts it to upper case**. Then in a very unrelated method call, it reverses the case of the string - so that any lower case letters become upper case letters... and **swaps any upper case letters to lower case letters**.

Comment: The Python 3 solution is **26** characters.

Comment: @Timtech I can't count.

Comment: It's not just unrelated. It's very unrelated.

Comment: This will have strange results when encountering text that contains the characters ß.

Answer (score 34):

**Perl** - <strike>11</strike> 10 characters.

```
y/A-Z/a-z/
```

`y///` is same as `tr///`!

In action:

```
% perl -pe 'y/A-Z/a-z/' <<< 'Hello @ WORLD !'
hello @ world !
```

Comment: +1, for the only real-life language that beat out all the less(?) real ones.

Comment: Actually that is 11 characters. The `-p` option is counted as 1.

Comment: @manatwork Or it should be counted as 2 : `-` and `p` :)

Comment: 1 if you assume `-e` (`perl -e` -> `perl -pe`), 3 if you assume a script (`perl` -> `perl -p`).

Comment: This could be 9 using `y;A-Z;a-z` instead!

Answer (score 10):

### Befunge-98 - <s>26 22 21</s> 19

```
~:''-d2*/1-!' *+,#@
```

Relies on the fact that `(c-39)/26` is `1` only for character codes of uppercase ASCII characters (assuming integer division).  For each character `c`, print out `c + (((c-39)/26)==1)*' '`.

Sample session:

```
% cfunge lower.b98
hello WORLD!
hello world!
This is a TEST!!11 az AZ @[`{
this is a test!!11 az az @[`{
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Python 3, 48

```
input().translate({c:c|32for c in range(65,91)})
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  I'm really interested in getting better at Python.  I don't get how the `map(ord,input())` bit works.

Comment: @JeffGohlke: `map` applies a function (in this case, `ord`) to an interable and returns an iterable. It’s like a shorter form of `(ord(x) for x in input())`.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Your answer follows the *spirit* of the question, but mine follows the *letter* of the question...

Comment: Very nice.  Beat my unposted 62 length solution `for c in input():print([c,(chr(ord(c)+32))]['@'<c<'['],end='')`.  I tried some with the `map(ord,input())` trick, but missed the multiplying the truth value by 32 and adding it to the character code trick.  Very nice.

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby, 18 characters

Nothing really interesting.

```
gets.tr'A-Z','a-z'
```

(run in IRB)

Just for fun: a confusing version:

```
$,=$* *' ';$;=$,.tr'A-Z','a-z';$><<$;
```

Run like this:

```
c:\a\ruby>lowercase.rb Llamas are AMAZING!
```

Output

```
llamas are amazing!
```

Answer (score 7):

### J - 30

```
'@Z'(]+32*1=I.)&.(a.&i.)1!:1]1
```

J is read right-to-left, so to break this down:

1. Prompt user for input: `1!:1]1`
2. Perform algorithm in code-point-space:  `&.(a.&i.)`
3. Identify character range for each letter; the characters between codepoints "@" and "Z" are considered uppercase: `1=I.`.
4. For each uppercase codepoint, add 32: `]+32* ...`
5. Note that step (2) creates an implicit step (5): we started out by projecting from character to integer domain, so now that we're finished, we map those integers back onto characters.

Obviously this particular implementation only considers ASCII; but the approach could be extended to at least the basic multilingual plane in Unicode.

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, it seems your solution is going the WRONG WAY. ;-)  Should be an easy fix though.  (Edit: `'@Z'(]+32*1=I.)&.(a.&i.)1!:1]1` should do it)

Comment: Nice catch, thanks.  I'm also impressed you were able to fix the code yourself: J isn't the most immediately-accessible language out there :)

Comment: Ah, I've played around some with J myself.. I managed to come up with `u:(a.i.x)+32*1='@Z'I.x=.1!:1]1`, which matches your length but is much less interesting (as it doesn't make use of 'under'). Speaking of which, I didn't know about dyadic `I.`, so thanks for using that. :-)

Comment: Cool. But your Befunge solution still has J beat by 4 characters. Obviously I can't let that stand :) I'm trying to see if trim the J solution down by following your lead in relying solely on '@', rather than both '@' and 'Z'.

Comment: `(32(23)b.])&.(3&u:)`, should be 5 bytes shorter.

Comment: `23 b.&32&.(3&u:)`

Answer (score 7):

**C <strike>64 63 59</strike> 55 chars**

```
main(c){while(c=getchar(),~c)putchar(c-65u<27?c+32:c);}
```

Comment: I count only 63 characters there.

Comment: You can lose 9 characters: drop `int ` and `,c>=0`. They're not necessary here.

Comment: we need c>=0 as getchar(EOF) will be < 0. Thanks for other suggestion.

Comment: 1. `~(c=getchar())` 2. `c-64u<27`

Comment: Thats great, have incorporated your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: You can save one more by `c=~getchar()`. It will require some work on your `putchar` though.

Comment: Insignificantly small bug: seems there should be 65 instead of 64. http://pastebin.com/Zc9zMx2W

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1mzujwjMydVoyg1MUXDQEctWcdQU7OgtCQ5I7FII1nXzLTUxsjMPlnb2MgqWdO69v9/BUUlZRVVNXUNTS1tHV09fQNDI2MTUzNzC0sraxtbO3sHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomNi4@ITEpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKquqa2rp/yWk5ienF/3XLAQ), also fixed a bug with `[` being translated to `{`

Answer (score 6):

**Golfscript - 17**

Program:

```
{..64>\91<*32*+}%
```

Explanation:

1. `{}%` maps the code inside to every character in string.
2. `..` copies the top of the stack (the character) twice.
3. `64>` 1 if character code is greater than 64, else 0.
4. `\` swaps the two items on the stack (gets the second copy of the letter, and stores the result of `64>` in position two).
5. `91<` checks to see if character code is less than 91. Similar to step 3.
6. `*` multiplies the results from steps 3 and 5 together. Only equal to 1, if both steps were true.
7. `32*` multiplies the result of step 6 with 32. Will be 32 if step 6 was 1, else 0.
8. `+` add the result (either 32 or 0) onto the character code.

Example output:

```
echo HelLO @ WorLD | ruby golfscript.rb upper_to_lower.gs
hello @ world
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
u.š
```

Port of [*@user8777* Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12774/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/VO/owv//QzIyixU8ixUcFYIS81LycxVCUotLFJQNFQE)

**Explanation:**

```python
u    # Convert the (implicit) input to uppercase
 .š  # Switch the case (upper to lower and vice-versa)
     # (and output the result implicitly)
```

---

But without any case-altering builtins:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```python
žn2ä`‡
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*.
-5 bytes thanks to *@TheThonnu*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L48o8NLEh41LPz/3yM1JydfRyE8vygnRREA)

**Explanation:**

```python
žn      # Push builtin string "ABC...XYZabc...xyz"
  2ä    # Split it into two equal-sized parts: ["ABC...XYZ", "abc...xyz"]
    `   # Pop and push the strings separately to the stack
     ‡  # Transliterate all uppercase letters to lowercase ones
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: `ÇIS.u32*+çJ` saves a byte on your 12-byte version.

Comment: @Emigna Ah, smart. I had tried the `.u32*+` approach like this: `εÇy.u32*+ç]J`, but unfortunately `ç` wraps the characters in a list, so an additional `J` or ` was required after the `ç`..

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L48I7PDWxIeNSz8/98jNScnX0chPL8oJ0URAA "05AB1E – Try It Online") (no case-altering built-ins)

Comment: @TheThonnu Thanks! And `26ô` can actually be `2ä`. :) `ä` (split into that many equal sized parts) is kinda the opposite of `ô` (split into parts of that size).

Comment: Nice: I was looking for that (as I knew it existed), but it's documented as "slice" not "split", so I couldn't find it :(

Answer (score 4):

## Perl: 24 characters

```perl
s/[A-Z]/chr 32+ord$&/ge
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ perl -pe 's/[A-Z]/chr 32+ord$&/ge' <<< 'Hello @ WORLD !'
hello @ world !
```

Comment: Hem, why `chr ord` ?  I'm pretty sure you won't learn anything in reading my answer ;-)

Comment: Amazing trick, @F.Hauri!

Comment: @nyuszika7h, the +1 is the `-p` command line parameter, not a newline.

Comment: Oh right, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

### javascript 80

```
"X".replace(/[A-Z]/g,function($){return String.fromCharCode($.charCodeAt()+32)})
```

(76 if you remove `"X"`)

with `prompt` and `alert` - **92**

```
alert(prompt().replace(/[A-Z]/g,function($){return String.fromCharCode($.charCodeAt()+32)}))
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/mhLXe/)

thanks to @FireFly @some @C5H8NNaO4 and @minitech

Comment: Er, you'd need to wrap the second argument to `replace` with `function($){return ...}`, no?  By the way, the first param to the replacement function is the matched string, so you could drop the parens in the regex.

Comment: How would i go about running it,like this?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 str(code here)

Comment: I guess for a valid input you should at least assume,  it, to be predefined. costs only a char

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 three (1)`"`(2)`char`(3)`"`, its already pretty long, and the other answers dont have it. u can test this code if u want to see it run though `"TeSt".replace(/[A-Z]/,function($){return String.fromCharCode($.charCodeAt()+32)})`

Comment: I think all (or at least most) answers in here read from stdin and print to stdout. From what I gather the convention is to use `prompt` and `alert` for I/O in JS.

Comment: If you had tested your code, you would have fond that it only converts the first upper case character, not all of them. It's 92 characters, when following the rules: `alert(prompt().replace(/[A-Z]/g,function(a){return String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt()+32)}))`

Comment: You need a `/g` flag for this to work properly.

Comment: @some there is no rule which requires `alert` and `prompt`, but i will edit in that as well

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Somehow you must get the user supplied string into the program, and show the result. When code golfing in javascript the common way is to use `prompt` and `alert`. The rules doesn't say anything about it since the rules are language agnostic. If you look at the other answers you will see that they use the equivalent statements to do input/output in their respective languages. So why do you think that you don't need it when writing in javascript?

Comment: @some i figured that maybe it could be part of the program (as in my example), but since u commented i added one with `prompt` and `alert` as well, i dont see anything wrong with it now.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Well, in that case I can write a program that is 0 characters long, pretending that everything else somehow is part of the program. Does that feel fair? Now your code works since it almost a verbatim copy of what I wrote, but you are using `$` as a variable name. While it is legal, it is a bit confusing since `$` mostly is used by libraries like jQuery. I also noticed that you didn't credit me or anyone else for finding bugs in your code.

Comment: It's 80 bytes, not 79.

Answer (score 3):

#### JavaScript - <s>109</s> 104 (ES6: 95)

Thanks to some for the corrected version.

```js
a=prompt();for(b=[i=0];c=a.charCodeAt(i);)b[i++]=String.fromCharCode(c|(c>64&c<91)*32);alert(b.join(""))
```

The following works if the browser supports ES6 function expressions:

```js
alert(prompt().split("").map(c=>String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()|(c>"@"&c<"[")*32)).join(""))
```

Comment: The first code doesn't work (tested in FF and Chrome) because when trying to get a character after the length of the string, you get `undefined` and then `c.charCodeAt()` fails because undefined don't have `charCodeAt`. A working example 105 characters: `a=prompt();for(b=[i=0];c=a.charCodeAt(i);)b[i++]=String.fromCharCode(c|(c>64&&c‌​<91)*32);alert(b.join(''))`

Comment: @some oops, I wonder how I came up with that snippet.. I'm pretty sure I tested that code, maybe I copied a non-working version in or something. Anyway, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Using a bitwise `and` instead of a logical one... nice!

Comment: An _even more ES6_ solution (**79**): `L=s=>[String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()|(c>"@"&c<"[")*32)for(c of s)].join('')`. Usage: `L('SoMeTeXt')`

Comment: Nice! I'm not sure about making it a mere function though, since all other solutions are "proper" programs. Still, very nice use of `for..of` regardless.

Answer (score 3):

**DELPHI**

```
const
  UpChars:set of AnsiChar = ['A'..'Z'];
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(pString));
  for I := 1 to length(pstring) do
    Result[i] := AnsiChar((Integer(pString[i] in UpChars))*(Ord(pString[i])+32));
  WriteLn(Result);
end;
```

Comment: This is not golf. Don't you feel this piece is very different compared to others ?

Comment: @ray Golfing is about getting your code as short as possible. Delphi isnt a great language for golfing. I use delphi myself and even though there isnt a big chance I could win a golf with delphi, its still fun to challenge yourself.

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl 18

```
s/[A-Z]/$&|" "/eg
```

Something like:

```
perl -pe 's/[A-Z]/$&|" "/eg'  <<<'are NOT allowed to: ToLower() in .NET, strtolower() in PHP'
are not allowed to: tolower() in .net, strtolower() in php
```

and

```
perl -pe 's/[A-Z]/$&|" "/eg' <<< "The input string Doesn't cOntaIn...( C0D3-@01F. ;-)"
the input string doesn't contain...( c0d3-@01f. ;-)
```

For [@FireFly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/29281) :

```
perl -pe 's/[A-Z]/$&|" "/eg' <<< "Doesn't this translate @ to \` and [\]^_ to {|}~DEL? "
doesn't ... @ to ` and [\]^_ to {|}~del?
```

no.

#### More generic: 18 chars anyway:

```
s/[A-Z]/$&|" "/eg
```

```
s/[A-Z]/$&^" "/eg
```

This wont change anything in state:

```
perl -pe 's/[A-Z]/$&^" "/eg' <<< "Doesn't ... @ to \` and [\]^_ to {|}~DEL? "
doesn't ... @ to ` and [\]^_ to {|}~del?
```

All work fine, but the advantage of changing `|` (or) by `^` (xor) is that the same syntax could be used for `toLower`, `toUpper` or `swapCase`:

toUpper:

```
perl -pe 's/[a-z]/$&^" "/eg' <<< "Doesn't ... @ to \` and [\]^_ to {|}~DEL? "
DOESN'T ... @ TO ` AND [\]^_ TO {|}~DEL?
```

and swapCase **(18+1 = 19 chars)**:

```
perl -pe 's/[a-z]/$&^" "/egi' <<< "Doesn't ... @ to \` and [\]^_ to {|}~DEL? "
dOESN'T ... @ TO ` AND [\]^_ TO {|}~del?
```

Comment: I forgot +1 for `-p` sorry @manatwork

Comment: Doesn't this translate `@` to backtick and `[\]^_` to `{|}~DEL`? And therein lies the tricky part..

Comment: @FireFly No, `$&` have to match `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Very cool, then!

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, 15 bytes

Assembled:

```
ac3c 417c 063c 5a7f 020c 20aa e2f2 c3
```

Unassembled listing:

```
       _LOOP:
 AC         LODSB            ; load byte from [SI] into AL, advance SI 
 3C 41      CMP  AL, 'A'     ; is char less than 'A'? 
 7C 06      JL   _STORE      ; if so, do not convert 
 3C 5A      CMP  AL, 'Z'     ; is char greater than 'Z'? 
 7F 02      JG   _STORE      ; if so, do not convert 
 0C 20      OR   AL, 'a'-'A' ; lowercase the char 
       _STORE:
 AA         STOSB            ; store char to [DI], advance DI 
 E2 F2      LOOP _LOOP       ; continue loop through string 
 C3         RET              ; return to caller
```

Callable near function. Input string in `DS:[SI]`, length in `CX`. Output string in `ES:[DI]`.

Output from PC DOS test program:

[image]

Comment: where is the 14 byte count coming from?  the snippet is longer than that, even without comments... is 14 bytes the compiled program?

Comment: @Jonah The byte opcode is in the lefthand column, `AC 3C 41`, etc. I'll add the assembled hex byte code to the top for clarity. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12340/84624

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
{`c$x+32*~"A["'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pOSFap0DY20qpTcoxWUq+o5eJKU1DySM3JyddRCM8vyklRVAIA1kgK9g==)

Avoids using the `floor` builtin (`_:`).

- `~"A["'` generate a bit mask with 1's in the positions in the input containing uppercase letters
- `32*` multiply by 32, which calculates the offsets between uppercase and lowercase ASCII character codes
- `x+` add the offsets to the input (converting the string input to integers)
- `` `c$ `` convert back to characters

Answer (score 2):

### R

#### 71 characters:

```
chartr(paste(LETTERS,collapse=""),paste(letters,collapse=""),scan(,""))
```

#### 83 characters:

```
a=as.integer(charToRaw(scan(,"")))
b=a%in%(65:90)
a[b]=a[b]+32
rawToChar(as.raw(a))
```

Comment: That's `86` characters - newlines count as 2 characters. (http://www.string-functions.com/length.aspx)

Comment: @Timtech: In R you can replace newlines in code by `;` so no they count just for one character. It could be written: `a=as.integer(charToRaw(scan(,"")));b=a%in%(65:90);a[b]=a[b]+32;rawToChar(as.raw(a))`

Comment: Yes, now I realized. I read up on meta... seems that only on Windows that newlines are 2 characters (I was using a program to measure the length of my code).

Answer (score 2):

## Q, 18

.....

```
{x^ssr/[x]..Q`a`A}
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP (42)

Run from the command line:

```
-R'echo@str_ireplace($a=range(a,z),$a,$argn);'
```

`-R` and the single quotes are not counted.

Comment: If you follow Gowtham's Peal solution, you would only count 42 characters.

Comment: @eisberg: Updated the score, leaving a 43-character version in the history in case of any dispute.

Comment: `str_ireplace` does case insensitive search, which is stretching the rules, if not breaking them.

Comment: @ugoren I do not think so. As it is clearly stated that only build in function changing the case are not allowed and this is ignoring the case not changing it.

Answer (score 2):

## Q (16)

.......

```
{x^(.Q.A!.Q.a)x}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python (33)

If in doubt, use the shell.

```
import os;os.system('tr A-Z a-z')
```

Regrettably, this is still longer than Lego's solution.

Comment: +1 That is indeed not a Python built-in you are using. Only works on linux, but still very rule-bendy!!!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Works everywhere there is a `tr` command (which does the right thing) on the path of the invoked shell, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell: <strike>69</strike> <strike>65</strike> 64

I've tried a half-dozen ways to get Replace to work the way I want it to without using the long `[regex]::Replace` syntax, but I haven't had any luck. If anyone else has an idea of what might work, please do suggest it.

**Golfed code:**

```
[regex]::Replace((read-host),"[A-Z]",{[char](32+[char]"$args")})
```

> **Changes from original:**
>
> - Rearranged last argument so that `[int]` is no longer needed, per suggestion in comments.

**Explanation:**

`(read-host)` gets the user input.

`[regex]::Replace(`...`)` tells PowerShell to use RegEx matching to perform replacement operations on a string.

`"[A-Z]"` matches all uppercase letters.

`{`...`}` tells PowerShell to use a script to determine the replacement value.

`[char]"$args"` takes the current match and types it as an ASCII character.

`32+` converts the character to an integer, representing the ASCII code, and increases the value by 32 - which would match ASCII code of the corresponding lowercase letter.

`[char](`...`)` takes the resulting value and converts it back to an ASCII character.

Demo of original:

[image]

(Current version tested - screenshot not yet posted.)

Comment: Haven't checked on how to get around that `[regex]::Replace`, but you can save 4 chars by changing `[int]` to `+`

Comment: Actually, the whole last argument can be rearranged to `{[char](32+[char]"$args")}`, which removes the need to explicitly cast to int and shaves off one more character

Comment: @goric Geez, why didn't I think of that already? Still learning, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

## k2, 15 bytes

I am *super* late to this one, but I found this cool anyway.

```
{_ci 32+_ic x}'
```

Also:

## Pyth, 10 bytes

Doesn't really count because Pyth was created after this was posted. Still cool.

```
jkmC+32Cdw
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>53</s> <s>49</s> 43 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks @AdmBorkBork*

*-6 bytes thanks @Veskah*

```powershell
-join($args|%{[char](32*($_-in65..90)+$_)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0MlsSi9uEa1Ojo5I7EoVsPYSEtDJV43M8/MVE/P0kBTWyVes1bzfy2XSoWCrYKSh6uPj79CeH5RToqigmeJQmaxgqeOQgDI5GCQyQrupZWKSlxqKmkKDhVcEE0Qe9Qd1fX01KPUtdUTQYwqdU2oqv8A)

Comment: cool! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: [Splat it up for 43](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0MlsSi9uEa1Ojo5I7EoVsPYSEtDJV43M8/MVE/P0kBTWyVes1bzfy2XSoWCrYKSh6uPj79CeH5RToqigmeJQmaxgqeOQgDI5GCQyQrupZWKSlxqKmkKDhVcEE0Qe9Qd1fX01KPUtdUTQYwqdU2oqv8A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Vim, 6 bytes

`gUUg~~`

Or, if allowed,

### Vim, 3 bytes

`guu`

Comment: `ggguG`, I'd count that as built-in tho. :^)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, because Java's my language.

## Java - <s>162</s> 175

Fixed for OP's updates.

```
class a{public static void main(String[]a){String b="";for(char c:new java.util.Scanner(
System.in).nextLine().toCharArray())b+=c>64&&c<91?(char)(c+32):c;System.out.print(b);}}
```

**With line breaks and tabs**

```
class a{

    public static void main(String[]a){
        String b="";
        for(char c:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray())b+=c>64&&c<91?(char)(c+32):c;
        System.out.print(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: See the question owner's [recent comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/converting-a-string-to-lower-case-without-built-in-to-lower-functions/12761#comment25170_12760).

Comment: manatwork is right. And in the challenge, I also wrote **ASCII string**, so it would be very unlikely that the input string would contain uppercase characters only.

Comment: Okay, will update when I get home.

Comment: @ProgramFOX Updated.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - 70

Updated for OP's changes.

I'm a Python newbie, so any critique is welcome.

```
print("".join(chr(ord(c)+32) if 64<ord(c)<91 else c for c in input()))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to say that you're not allowed to use a to-lower function on one character. Question updated.

Comment: Please see [my recent comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/converting-a-string-to-lower-case-without-built-in-to-lower-functions/12761#comment25170_12760): your code does only work if the input string contains only uppercase characters, but please note that it also contain other ASCII characters such as lowercase characters and numbers.

Comment: Okay, will update when I get home

Comment: @ProgramFOX Updated.

Comment: Jeff, check out [@minitechs answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12765/8777). You both have very similar approaches so you should be able to see how, and *why* his answer is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 105

```
prompt().split("").map(function(a){c=a.charCodeAt(0);return String.fromCharCode(c|(c-64?32:0))}).join("")
```

<sub>Actually ther was no output form specified, so run it in console</sub>
<sub>Yea, JavaScript really is verbose with charcode <-> string</sub>

Comment: `c.charCodeAt()` -- it defaults to `0` if an index is omitted.  Also, breaks on '@' I believe (it gets "lowercased" into backtick)

Comment: @FireFly Nice, Thanks!, ok i'll gonna fix it =)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby: 66

```
def l(s)s.bytes.map{|b|(65..90).include?(b)?b+32:b}.pack('c*');end
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 108

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){foreach(var c in a[0])System.Console.Write(
(char)(c>64&&c<91?c+32:c));}}
```

About 70 for just the method body.

Add 5 chars to include a LF/CR in the output:

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){foreach(var c in a[0]+"\n")System.Console.Write(
(char)(c>64&&c<91?c+32:c));}}
```

A LINQ version would be shorter:

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){a[0].Any(c=>System.Console.Write(
(char)(c>64&&c<91?32+c:c))is P);}}
```

(103) .. except that it requires `using System.Linq;` (total: 121).

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 58

```
p x|(elem x['A'..'Z'])=[x..]!!32|1<2=x
main=interact$map p
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 9 + 1 (for -p flag) = 10

```
$_="\L$_"
```

`\L` was specifically asked about and allowed, because even though it's a built-in, it's not a function.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>39</sup> 30 bytes

```
(<&91*64&<)`(,:32+])}&.(a.i.])
```

*-9 thanks to xash*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWzULA21zEzUbDQTNHSsjI20YzVr1fQ0EvUy9WI1/2typSZn5CukKSioJzolu6S6KTooOqj/BwA)

Uses [Item Amend](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d530n.htm) `}` to choose which characters need to be lowercased and which passed through unaltered.

It applies this operation "under" conversion to ascii indexes `&.(a.i.])` -- it first converts the string to the indexes of its characters, than applies the item amend transformation, then converts back.

The item amend transformation is defined by the gerund `` (<&91*64&<)`(,:32+]) ``.  `(,:32+])` defines the two possibilities: the input unaltered, or the the input shifted 32 places to the right, converting `A` to `a`, etc.  `(<&91*64&<)` determines which integers go into which transformation category: If an integer is greater than 64 and less than 91 -- ie, the integers corresponding to `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` -- it gets shifted by 32.

Comment: Monadic `}` works here neatly to choose between +32 and unaltered: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWzULA21zEzUbDQTNHSsjI20YzVr1fQ0EvUy9WI1/2typSZn5CukKSioJzolu6S6KTooOqj/BwA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: Very nice.  I typically forget about item amend, but occasionally it's the perfect tool.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), <s>92</s> 90 bytes

```
2x1v8a8m2x2v2d3m5s2x3v1x1f1r3x1v4e3x2v2g1o1f0x1x2f3x3v3l1o1f0x1x3f8a8a8a8a1o1f0x1x4f0a0x1f
```

Works for any null-terminated input string.

[Try it online!](https://sporeball.dev/naz/?code=2x1v8a8m2x2v2d3m5s2x3v1x1f1r3x1v4e3x2v2g1o1f0x1x2f3x3v3l1o1f0x1x3f8a8a8a8a1o1f0x1x4f0a0x1f&input=HELLO%252C%2520WORLD!&n=true)

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
2x1v                   # Set variable 1 equal to 0
8a8m2x2v               # Set variable 2 equal to 64 ("@")
2d3m5s2x3v             # Set variable 3 equal to 91 ("[")
1x1f1r3x1v4e3x2v2g1o1f # Function 1
                       # Read a byte of input
                       # Goto function 4 if it equals variable 1
                       # Goto function 2 if it's greater than variable 2
                       # Otherwise, output it and call the function again
1x2f3x3v3l1o1f         # Function 2
                       # Goto function 3 if the register is less than variable 3
                       # Otherwise, output and jump to function 1
1x3f8a8a8a8a1o1f       # Function 3
                       # Add 32 to the register, output, and call function 1
1x4f0a                 # Function 4
                       # Add 0 to the register
1f                     # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
⇧N
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%87%A7N&inputs=AbC&header=&footer=)

This is the same as the 05ab1e answer but shorter because overloads.

### Non-trivial version

```
kAkaĿ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=c&code=kAka%C4%BF&inputs=AbC&header=&footer=)

Funnily enough, [I've used this before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224710/78850).

```
kAka    # Push "ABC...XYZ" and "abc...xyz"
    Ŀ   # Transliterate input with the above strings
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
x->map(c->c+32('@'<c<'['),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/QtcuN7FAI1nXLlnb2EhD3UHdJtlGPVpdU6dC839xSZGCrYJzRmKRnoaxkZWhkZmmQo2dQlZ@Zh5XQVFmXklOngZQjSackwbmovMVbG0VcvLLU4uSE4tTISr@AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 44 bytes

```
N
Count i while _ {
Write _+_/65*90/_*32
N
}
```

Outputs with a trailing newline. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXqGaK7woswTI0o7XNzPVsjTQj9cyNuLy46r9/19BUUlZRVVNXUNTS1tHV0/fwNDI2MTUzNzC0sraxtbO3sHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomNi4@ITEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orKquqa2DgA)

#### Explanation

The joke's on you, OP: *Acc!!* doesn't even *have* built-in to-lower functions... >:^D

`N` reads a byte from stdin into the accumulator; then we loop while that value is nonzero (i.e. we haven't yet reached end-of-input). We want to add 32 to the character code iff the input is an uppercase letter--that is, if its character code is between 65 and 90. Lacking comparison operators, we use int division:

```
Code range | _/65 | 90/_ | (_/65)*(90/_)
-----------|------|------|--------------
32-64      | 0    | >0   | 0
65-90      | 1    | 1    | 1
90-126     | >0   | 0    | 0
```

Now observe that `_/65` will always be either 0 or 1 for all values of `_` in the range we're interested in. So we can drop the parentheses: `_/65*90/_` is equivalent to `(_/65*90)/_`, which is `90/_` if `_` is >= 65 and `0` otherwise. Thus, our conditional lowercase formula is simply `_+_/65*90/_*32`. We write the corresponding character, read a new one, and loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]/g,x=>parseInt(x,36).toString(36))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLBbtswDIbvfgr2VBuw3UOBHQqkQDAMW4CiK9Bc1mFAGZm21SmiIVFZ@vQpbadLsO4mUST/j/z1gjuMJthBKs8NHdrFIS5uYx1ocGgov/q5rJ5@XXXlfnE7YIi08pLvy@tPRS38KMH6LtdLcTDsIzuqHXd5mz9n2bon6BgdcAvS2whG@1cduxb0IgwmEAoBTg@aggKORJ@0MEUKYP2QBNDD8vHzagVxUoNclQStj8DevcKgQcGNo2OW6TGgEQqxKLW2gVdOQbO4C7gFTqI9Zw3HfyhUBiPBDoNFL39RZ6k6y1bbgYPo083YBzAQ3H9fA7qxuBmnUFIdYZOsk8p6aJM3YtnP8yjqjsJR752fA7ykqGKeTrTF2GsimoDymEwPGGHNd2MwL3QbUN9/WZdjH2F3ij58e4AS6rouLuAHp0tl/JfPqQuKED5yxhJ6TVVKnXbp5yz7PjVogG5gtHI24zhDwxT95TTfaMXsRBqGI/3Jg/pjra4XYWv347L/V1KereE86tN2o4fJ0xlzNvz0Ac5ks@wrcwMumd8X2bN@zzc)

From 12Me21's

Answer (score 0):

## Python - <del>96</del> <del>94</del> 82

```
for c in input():print(chr(ord(c)-65+97),end="")if c.isupper()else print(c,end="")
```

Ungolfed version:

```
for char in input():
    print(chr(ord(char) - (ord("A") - ord("a"))), end="") if char.isupper() \
    else print(char, end="")
```

Comment: You can replace `ord("A")` with `65` and `ord("a")` with `97` to save 12 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Because I felt like it (I know that I'm a bit late)

## Java - 162

```java
class a{public static void main(String[]a){for(char c:(new java.util.Scanner(System.in)).nextLine().toCharArray())System.out.print((char)((c>64&&c<91)?c+32:c));}}
```

expanded:

```java
public class a{
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        for (char c : (new java.util.Scanner(System.in)).nextLine().toCharArray()) {
            System.out.print((char) ((c > 64 && c < 91) ? c + 32 : c));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java - 119

```java
class a{static{for(char c:(new java.util.Scanner(System.in)).nextLine().toCharArray())System.out.print((char)(c|32));}}
```

Works for every character except `@` which becomes the back-tick (`` ` ``), and the following (foo:bar for foo becomes bar) :

```
\:|
]:}
^:~
_:
```

Even though this isn't a true solution because it has 5 cases where it doesn't work, I thought it was very interesting. It takes the characters of the input and does a bitwise or with `' '` (`c|32`).

I discovered that `c^32` swaps the case when the input is only letters while solving a [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problem. I wondered what would happen in I changed the XOR to an OR.

Answer (score 0):

### Game Maker Language, 228

Make script/function `s` with this code, **53** characters:

```
a=argument0;b=string_replace_all(b,string_upper(a),a)
```

Then, use this **175** character code:

```
b=get_string('','')s('a')s('b')s('c')s('d')s('e')s('f')s('g')s('h')s('i')s('j')s('k')s('l')s('m')s('n')s('o')s('p')s('q')s('r')s('s')s('t')s('u')s('v')s('w')s('x')s('y')s('z')
```

The input (stored in variable `b`), is now lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 124

The closest I got was 124 characters...

```
b=prompt();a=[];for(c=b.length;c--;)a[c]="@"<b[c]&"[">b[c]?String.fromCharCode(b[c].charCodeAt(0)+32):b[c];alert(a.join(""))
```

@Firefly, nice work with using the "map" command... I've yet to master it...

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell - 81 characters

### Program:

```
param($s);[char[]]$s|%{if($_-lt90-and$_-gt64){$n+=[char](+$_+32)}else{$n+=$_}};$n
```

### Example Usage:

```
.\lower.ps1 -s "TEST!"
```

### Output:

```
test!
```

### How it works:

It just adds 32 to the decimal value of the ASCII character, which is the lowercase version.
It only does this if it is within 64-90, which is all capital letters.

Comment: I don't know where you got 63 from. That's 81 characters. http://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Answer (score 0):

#### Delphi XE3 (153 chars)

```
uses System.SysUtils;var u:string;i:int8;begin readln(u);for i:=1to Length(u)do if CharInSet(u[i],['A'..'Z'])then u[i]:=Chr(Ord(u[i])+32);writeln(u);end.
```

Not a winner but fun to do :)

#### with indent

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;
var
  u:string;
  i:int8;
begin
  readln(u);
  for i:=1to Length(u)do
    if CharInSet(u[i],['A'..'Z'])then
      u[i]:=Chr(Ord(u[i])+32);
    writeln(u);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

### J 35

```
echo(+32*64&<*.95&>)&.(a.&i.)1!:1]3
```

Using the magical under `&.`. This looks up the ascii code, then adds 32 * the boolean `inRange` , where `inRange` is `x>64 and x<91`. The under operation automatically applies the inverse lookup afterwards, resulting in the wanted lowercase.

In action:

```
   echo(+32*64&<*.91&>)&.(a.&i.)1!:1]3
Hello World AZ!
hello world az!
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 78 bytes

```
t=input()
for c in t:
 x=ord(c)
 if 64<x<91:t=t.replace(c,chr(x+32))
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;dBíC
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O2RC7UM&input=IjEyQWFCYkNjMzQi)

Answer (score 0):

## [q](https://kx.com/download) 37 bytes

```
{$[x in .Q.A;x:(.Q.A!.Q.a)[x];x]}each
```

## Explanation

```
$[x in .Q.A          // If the character is in the capitals list
  x:(.Q.A!.Q.a)[x]   // Create a key mapping between upper and lower case letters,
                     // and set x to it's pair
  x]}                // else, just return the character
  each               // apply to each character in string passed in
```

## Example

```
q){$[x in .Q.A;x:(.Q.A!.Q.a)[x];x]}each "LoWersWFSfdgSA"
"lowerswfsfdgsa"
```

Comment: `{x^.Q.a .Q.A?x}` for **15 bytes**.

Comment: Very nice. never use lookup, was surprised to see it index non-list members as just out-of-bounds (26).

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 58 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]/g,x=>(x.charCodeAt()-55).toString(36))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 55 bytes

```forth
: f 0 do dup i + c@ dup 65 91 within 32 * - emit loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRgopOQrpJQWKGQqaCskO4CZZqYKloYK5ZklGZl5CsZGCloKugqpuZklCjn5@QUK1v@LlRQcE52SnJOjqqJjTc2UFNL@AwA)

#### Explanation

Iterates through the string, for each character:

- Gets the ascii value of the character
- If between 65 and 90 (inclusive) add 32, else leave as is
- Print the char corresponding to that value

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                   \ start new word definition
  0 do                \ start counted loop from 0 to string-length - 1
    dup i +           \ duplicate the string address and add the loop index
    c@                \ get the ascii char value at that address
    dup 65 91 within  \ check if value is between 65 and 90 (-1 = true, 0 = false)
    32 * -            \ multiply result by 32 and subtract from original number
    emit              \ output value
  loop                \ end loop
;                     \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 17 bytes

```
i::" @["{)${(**+o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKSknBIVqpWlOlWkNLSzv//3@P1BxDRWWFaIfYnHw9AA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript(ES6), 92/90 bytes

```
prompt().split('').map(x=>String.fromCharCode((y=x.charCodeAt(),y>64&y<91)?y+32:y)).join('')
```

```
l=a=>a.split('').map(x=>String.fromCharCode((y=x.charCodeAt(),y>64&y<91)?y+32:y)).join('')
```

Turn the input string into a char array, turn all uppercase letters into lowercase, and turn it back into a string.(Difference between uppercase letter and lowercase letter('a'-'A') is 32, 64 is '@', 91 is '['.)

If using alerts is required, that increases the characters by 7, which means it's 99 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [FALSE](https://github.com/somebody1234/FALSE), 29 bytes

```
[^$1_=~][$$64>\91>~&[32+]?,]#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/z86TsUw3rYuNlpFxczELsbS0K5OLdrYSDvWXidW@f9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 113 bytes

```
/~/\/\///Q/q~W/w~E/e~R/r~T/t~Y/y~U/u~I/i~O/o~P/p~A/a~S/s~D/d~F/f~G/g~H/h~J/j~K/k~L/l~Z/z~X/x~C/c~V/v~B/b~N/n~M/m/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJHFsFQAEDRJb016L13xyQIQdSvD97Ww7k3pFFI4pBlyOIPelyd8LJEbJ@bQ@7O@DjiYY2dHc52uZgjckCwyNoyGytsrZJYZ2@Dg01S53yd8rbAyjFP8yxtc7LFkSz7AQ)

Simply replaces all the uppercase characters with lowercase. Because there's no other way to take input in ///, it is hardcoded:

```
/~/\/\///Q/q~W/w~E/e~R/r~T/t~Y/y~U/u~I/i~O/o~P/p~A/a~S/s~D/d~F/f~G/g~H/h~J/j~K/k~L/l~Z/z~X/x~C/c~V/v~B/b~N/n~M/m/INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

## batch 112 bytes

**lower.bat**

```bat
@Set "s=%~1"&@for %%c in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)do @Set "s=!s:%%c=%%c!"
@Echo(!s!
```

*Notes:*

- requires cmd.exe's codepage to be `430` or `850`, to change codepage, use: `CHCP 430` or `CHCP 850`
- Must be started in the directory containing **`lower.bat`** using:
  `Echo(Lower "String to convert"|CMD /V:On`

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>61</s> 59 bytes

*-2 thanks to @ceilingcat*

```c
main(i){while(i=getchar()-10)putchar(i+(i>54&i<81?42:10));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzujwjMydVI9M2PbUkOSOxSENT19BAs6AUwsnU1si0MzVRy7SxMLQ3MbICSmla1/7/X1ieWlRSWZqZX5BYnJKWnpGVnVNVkVyWlJcbGO4aFBIZ6ukf4Bjs4ubu4eXtExXhHObk58sFAA)

Ungolfed:

```c
int main(i){
    while((i=getchar()) != '\n') {
        if(i>64&i<91){ // uppercase ASCII range is 65-92
            putchar(i+32); // lowercase ASCII range is 97-122
        } else {
            putchar(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat I totally forgot to remove those braces when golfing it down

Answer (score 0):

## mmo (MMIX executable), 112 bytes (28 tetras)

(jxd)

```
00000000: 98090100 98010001 00000100 e0002000  Ƭµ¢¡Ƭ¢¡¢¡¡¢¡ṭ¡ ¡
00000010: e3ff0140 00000300 58ff0002 00000000  ẉ”¢@¡¡¤¡X”¡£¡¡¡¡
00000020: 83010000 31ff0140 7502ff20 31ff015b  ³¢¡¡1”¢@u£” 1”¢[
00000030: 7002ff02 c0010102 a3010000 e3ff0140  p£”£Ċ¢¢£ɲ¢¡¡ẉ”¢@
00000040: 00000601 f1fffff3 00000000 20000000  ¡¡©¢ȯ””ṙ¡¡¡¡ ¡¡¡
00000050: 98020008 00000001 980a00ff 00000000  Ƭ£¡®¡¡¡¢Ƭ½¡”¡¡¡¡
00000060: 00000100 980b0000 00000000 980c0001  ¡¡¢¡Ƭ¿¡¡¡¡¡¡Ƭ€¡¢
```

Disassembly and explanation:

```
98090100 lop_pre 1,0                (mmo v1, 0 tetras)
98010001 lop_loc 0,1                (start loading at next tetra)
00000100 256                        (which is 256)
E0002000    SETH $0,#2000           (set $0 to address of data segment)
E3FF0140 0H SETL $255,2F            (set $255 to address of handle)
00000300    TRAP 0,Fread,StdIn      (read in one character)
58FF0002    PBNN $0,1F              (skip next instr if not EOF)
00000000    TRAP 0,Halt,0           (quit)
83010000 1H LDBU $1,$0,0            (read that byte in)
31FF0140    CMP  $255,$1,'@'        (compare with '@')
7502FF20    ZSP  $2,$255,#20        (if greater, then set $2 to 0x20)
31FF015B    CMP  $255,$1,'['        (compare with '[')
7002FF02    ZSN  $2,$255,$2         (unless less, clear $2)
C0010102    OR   $1,$1,$2           (or in $2)
A3010000    STBU $1,$0,0            (store it back)
E3FF0140    SETL $255,2F            (set $255 to address of handle)
00000601    TRAP 0,Fwrite,StdOut    (write that byte out)
F1FFFFF3    JMP  0B                 (loop back)
00000000                            (padding for alignment)
20000000 2H OCTA Data_Segment,1     (the handle)
98020008 lop_skip 8                 (slightly cheaper than two zero tetras)
00000001                            (end of handle)
980A00FF lop_post 255               (postamble, rG = 255)
00000000
00000100                            (start execution at location 256)
980B0000 lop_stab                   (begin symbol table)
00000000                            (no symbols)
980C0001 lop_end 1                  (symtab is one tetra long)
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB/Octave, 29 bytes

```matlab
@(x)char(x+32*(x>64).*(x<91))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCMzkjsUijQtvYSEujws7MRFMPSNtYGmpq/k/MK9ZQdylOTHNwSylTMDRWcClT1/wPAA)
Output to standard output variable `Ans` and written to command window.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 bytes

```
RP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi4IClhQnJRdDuQvWeqT65PjrKJT7F_mkKEIEAQ)
Port of user8777's Python answer.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kAẠṆ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWK7IdH-5a8HBn25LipORiqOCCtR6pPjn-Ogrl_kU-KYoQQQA)
No uppercase/swap-case built-ins here.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ıDkAsƇ?C32+C
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhbrjmx0yXYsPtZu72xspO28pDgpuRgqtWCtR6pPjr-OQrl_kU-KIkQQAA)
No uppercase/swap-case/transliterate built-ins here.

##### Explanation

```python
RP  # Implicit input
R   # Convert to uppercase
 P  # Swap the case of each character
    # Implicit output
```

```python
kAẠṆ  # Implicit input
   Ṇ  # Transliterate the input
kA    # (from) the uppercase alphabet
  Ạ   # (to) the lowercase alphabet
      # Implicit output
```

```python
ıDkAsƇ?C32+C  # Implicit input
ı             # Map over the input string:
 D            #  Duplicate it
    sƇ        #  Pop one copy, and check if it's in
  kA          #  the uppercase alphabet
      ?       #  If it is:
       C      #   Convert to codepoint
        32+   #   Add 32
           C  #   And convert to character
              #  Otherwise, the character stays on top
              # Implicit output, joined
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 17 bytes

`#µ»ä26¹64+=S32*+«`

Reads string (surrounded by quotes) from standard input, prints the result to standard output

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=I7W75DI2uTY0Kz1TMzIqK6s=&in=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

## Explanation

````
#             ; read the string from standard input
 µ»   «       ; apply to each element
              ; implicitly print the result

ä             ; duplicate the character
 26¹64+       ; push the range from 65 to 90 ('A' through 'Z')
       =      ; vectorized equality check (of character and range)
        S     ; sum up the vector (1 if the char is in range, 0 otherwise)
         32*+ ; multiply by 32 and add to the character
```
````

Answer (score -1):

`bash`: 11 characters?

```
$ i="This is A STRING"
$ echo ${i,,}
this is a string
```

Comment: It's a built'in toLower function!

Comment: @F.Hauri I assume that you'd need to add this comment on _most_ of the answers in the thread.

Comment: @F.Hauri Wrong. That`s not a built-in *function*. That\`s a built-in case-modification *operator*.