# Convert to uppercase and lowercase without branching and comparisons

Tags: math, restricted-source, atomic-code-golf

Write two functions/programs which take an ASCII code of character (8-bit unsigned integer) and one of them converts char to uppercase and other to lowercase.

That is, they must be equivalent to following functions:

```
unsigned char toUpper(unsigned char c){
    if (c >= 97 && c <= 122) return c - 32;
    return c;
}
unsigned char toLower(unsigned char c){
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) return c + 32;
    return c;
}
```

However you are not allowed to use branching (`if`s, `goto`s), loops and comparison and logical operators. Recursion, language built-in functions, regular expressions, arrays and objects also not allowed.
You may use **only** arithmetic and bitwise operations on 8-bit unsigned integers.

**Score:**

1 - for `| & ^ ~ >> <<` operators
1.11 - for `+ -` operators
1.28 - for `*` operator
1.411 - for `/ %` operators

Answer with lowest total score (for two functions added) wins. If answers with equal score than first (oldest) answer wins.

Comment: Are regular expressions allowed? If yes, this is a duplicate of [Converting a string to lower-case](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12760/9275).

Comment: @ProgramFOX No.

Comment: This good valid question deserves more upvotes. If you are an anti-micro-optimization kind of a guy, then you shouldn't even be at this question, let alone allowing your own biases and prejudices to cloud your judgement and downvote this legitimate question. Also, off-topicly, I would be very interested (fascinated) to see how you generated those score numbers. I'm not criticizing them, rather, just the opposite, I'm intrigued. Mabey you could comment a link to a resource about it?

Comment: @lolzerywowzery How I chose scores: At start I defined approximate scores I want operations should have, like 1, 1.1, 1.3 and 1.4. Then with trial and error I modified them a bit so equal score is unlikely with small operator amount. Checked that in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### C, C++ and related languages, 6.22

```c
unsigned char toggle(unsigned char c, unsigned char lo, unsigned char hi)
{
    unsigned char m = (unsigned char)((lo - c) ^ (hi - c)) >> 7;
    return c ^ (m << 5);
}

unsigned char toUpper(unsigned char c)
{
    return toggle(c, 96, 122);
}

unsigned char toLower(unsigned char c)
{
    return toggle(c, 64, 90);
}
```

Comment: Your score is 12.44 - total score for 2 functions.

Comment: That seems unreasonable - there is only one instance of each operator, not two, and there was nothing in the rules to forbid factoring out common code.

Comment: One more time I failed writing rules.

Comment: If merging common code allowed, why not share all operators? (`char xor(char a, char b){return a^b}`) @Somnium

Answer (score 8):

### C and other languages with integer division, <s>15.204</s> <s>14.644</s> <s>14.084</s> 11.864

```
unsigned char toUpper(unsigned char c){
    return c - ((c/97) ^ (c/123)) << 5;
}

unsigned char toLower(unsigned char c){
    return c + ((c/65) ^ (c/91)) << 5;
}
```

Comment: Just realized that `toUpper` gives wrong value for n in range [194 - 245] and `toLower` for almost all n >= 130.

Comment: @Somnium. Afaik ASCII contains only 128 characters. Everything else is extended ASCII which does not seem to be part of your spec.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Forgot about that fact. Then your solution is ok.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 11.482

My functions I have found before posting question, I hope there will better ones.

```
unsigned char toUpper(unsigned char c){
    unsigned char a = c - 97;
    return c - ((32 - a / 26) & 32);
}
unsigned char toLower(unsigned char c){
    unsigned char a = c - 65;
    return c + ((32 - a / 26) & 32);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 9.042 step score

```c
uchar toUpper(uchar c){
    return c^(((uchar)(c+133)/230)<<5);
}
uchar toLower(uchar c){
    return c^(((uchar)(c+165)/230)<<5);
} // 9.042 step score
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/NCsIwEITvfYpBELK02tqqINE38Cp4EEFiWvdgGtIUEemz159gwZtzmGXY3Y9dNamU6v3d6rMu0ZqGK6PPUJeTQ/t22X8KfL2zVjsRkqJHhJec9q0zUEchQoeEimdFQWleZLReL0hGXfQlbOvbn4Tl4oeANMVqms1zNF5bNKp2umfjcT2xEYSACmCWn1DWDoI3mUQcs8R35i3rXqulGI2zfI/BDmaUgJPhUaZkOJmJArWLuv4J)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 2.11 existance score

```c
uchar sub(uchar a, uchar b) {return a-b;}
uchar shr(uchar a, uchar b) {return a>>b;}
uchar add(uchar a, uchar b) {return sub(a, sub(0, b));}
uchar isneg(uchar a) {return shr(a, 7);}
uchar reach230(uchar a) {return shr(add(isneg(a),isneg(sub(229,a))),1);}
uchar dif(uchar a) {uchar t=reach230(a); t=add(t,t); t=add(t,t); t=add(t,t); t=add(t,t); t=add(t,t); return t;}
uchar toUpper(uchar c){ return sub(c,dif(add(c,133))); }
uchar toLower(uchar c){ return add(c,dif(add(c,165))); }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBboQgEIbvPsVkkyaSZRNX0zYN2X2CXpv00AsCKoeiQUzTbHx2O4iih3YP5QAz8H/zDyNOtRCT@@6UVBUMpte1URJEwy0MfmfTfEA/lGmIOA0vUBK4WeUGa4CfSjYmi7Kx95TX6yblUt6Reku890dG8YFETvdG1Su5A9AZgedNaBUXTV5kf2jRPpTihIbAm@X5C@WEEHreCkld7WqEyF1ieU4Ypr6eo@4f8dKUi36ufes6tQ5SkBvshiKob8fTgp6LAltlsIGv7ddvYJDvwKfHAE7aOPjk2qT4swRwLUNmc1K1FlJ9yRgcj5rBqvGrs4hW6eEhy98hbh/mQEHT@AVNaOxKo@OMj8k4/QA)