# Implement "tac": Print lines from a file in reverse

Tags: code-golf, string

Between the [kitten question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59029/the-kitten-command) and seeing [this question at U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233014/how-does-the-command-sed-1ghd-reverse-the-contents-of-a-file) about some `sed` magic, how about implementing [`tac`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac)?

---

## Objective

Implement a program that will reverse and print the lines in a file.

---

## Input

A file, provided as a name or via standard input

---

## Output

The lines, reversed, to standard out.

---

## Scoring

Bytes of source code.

Comment: `tac` is a bit strange when it comes to trailing linefeeds. It transforms `a\nb\n` (trailing linefeed) into `b\na\n` and `a\nb` (no trailing linefeed) into  `ba\n`. Is this how our code it supposed to behave?

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242/8478)

Comment: Also, if we have to replicate tac's behavior, a 3 byte Bash answers that executes `tac` is only a matter of time...

Comment: At the time of writing this had 6 votes but 14 answers... Don't forget to vote for questions if you think they're interesting, folks!

Comment: @Dennis at this point probably best to leave undefined.

Comment: Would be interesting if the file is bigger than the available memory+swap.

Comment: @Dennis Makes sense to me. Visualize the lines of a file as horizontal rows, all ending with `\n`. `tac` reverses the order of these rows. If an `\n` is removed from the middle of the file, the row it terminated is joined to the next row, but in the case of the last line, there is no next row to join to.

Comment: What mean the reverse of a line? For "123\n" the reverse is "321\n" or "\n321"?

Answer (score 15):

### GS2, 3 bytes

```
* +
```

The three bytes are, in order, split lines, reverse, and join lines.

Answer (score 9):

## Perl, 11 bytes

```
$\=$_.$\}{
```

Behaves exactly like `tac`. This code requires the `-p` switch, which I have counted as 1 byte.

#### Test runs

```
$ echo -en 'a\nb' | perl -pe'$\=$_.$\}{' | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 61 0a                                         ba.
$ echo -en 'a\nb\n' | perl -pe'$\=$_.$\}{' | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 0a 61 0a                                      b.a.
```

#### How it works

As explained [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32884), the `-p` switch basically wraps `while (<>) { ... ; print }` around the program, so the source code is equivalent to

```
 while(<>)
 {
   $\ = $_ . $\
 }
 print
```

For each line of input, we prepend the current line (`$_`) to `$\` (initially undefined), updating the latter with the result.

After all lines have been processed, `print` prints the value of the local variable `$_` (undefined in this scope), followed by the output record separator (`$\`).

Comment: Care to explain how this works?

Comment: @xebtl Evilly. Adding the `-p` switch wraps your code in a loop that begins `while(<>){` and ends `} continue { print }`, which allows filtering input just by modifying `$_`. ``$\=$_.$\`` prepends each line of input to the output record terminator, and the `}{` ends the perl-supplied `while` block prematurely, so the `continue` block is no longer attached to it. So all the lines of input are added to ``$\`` in reverse order, then at the end the `continue { print }` eventually runs, printing "nothing" (`$_` will be undef after the end of input), but with a terminator of ``$\``.

Comment: @xebtl grr, code formatting in comments seems a bit broken where backslashes and backticks come near each other. Perhaps you can guess at what I was trying to say.

Comment: That really is devious.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @hobbs I've fixed the formatting. If inline code ends with a backslash, you can use double backticks instead.

Comment: @Dennis thank you for the help

Comment: You may have a problem if the last line of the input is not terminated with a newline.

Comment: @primo The first example shows what happens in this case. The output will be strange, but exactly like tac's.

Comment: You seem to have independently arrived at the same solution that Eugene van der Pijll did, in a 2001 Perl golf competition in which this was a question.

Comment: @msh210 Interesting. Do you happen to have a link?

Comment: @Dennis pages 18 ff of [this book](http://terje2.frox25.no-ip.org/perlgolf_history_070109.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
j_.z
```

`.z` is the input separated by lines as a list, `_` reverses it and `j` joins it by a character, which by default is `\n`.

Answer (score 8):

## [FlogScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FlogScript), 2 bytes

```
)"
```

(Try it on [anarchy golf](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb).)

The `)` enables `--in-out-line-array` mode, and the rest of the program is `"`, reversing the array of lines.

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 7 bytes

```
!rm`.*$
```

With a single regex, Retina runs in Match mode. This normally just prints the number of matches, but with `!` we configure it to print the actual matches instead (separated by linefeeds).

The actual regex is merely `.*$`. `.*` matches any line (potentially empty), because `.` can match any character except linefeeds. I'll get to the `$` in a minute.

How do we make it print the matches in reverse? By making use of .NET's right-to-left matching mode, activated with the `r`. This means the regex engine starts at the end of the string when looking for matches and works backwards.

Finally, the `m` makes the `$` match the end of a *line* instead of the end of the string. Why do we even need that? The trouble is that `.*` generates extraneous matches. Consider the regex substitution

```
s/a*/$0x/
```

applied to the input `baaababaa`. You'd think this would yield `baaaxbaxbaax`, but it actually gives you `baaaxxbaxxbaaxx`. Why? Because after matching `aaa` the engine's cursor is between the `a` and the `b`. Now it can't match any more `a`s, but `a*` is also satisfied with an empty string. This means, after every single match you get another empty match.

We don't want that here, because it would introduce additional empty lines, so we discard those extraneous matches (which are at the *beginnings* of the lines, due to the right-to-left mode) by requiring that matches include the end of the line.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 34 bytes

```
main=interact$concat.reverse.lines
```

[edit]

Saved one byte by replacing `unlines` with `concat`.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 7 bytes

```
qN/W%N*
```

Reads stdin, prints to stdout.

Explanation:

```
q       Get input.
N/      Split at newlines.
W%      Reverse list.
N*      Join with newlines.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
jb_.z
```

This reverses the order of the lines with a simple split-reverse-join approach, but [not quite like tac](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59239/implement-tac-print-lines-from-a-file-in-reverse/59249#comment142591_59239).

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jb_.z&input=a%0Ab%0Ac)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 52 bytes

```
import sys;print''.join(sys.stdin.readlines()[::-1])
```

Comment: Doesn't input() read one line from stdin?

Comment: @Mauris Edited it

Comment: What about ```import sys;print sys.stdin.read()[::-1]``` ?

Comment: @dieter That reverses each character, the challenge asks for just the lines to be reversed

Comment: ok my bad - Didn't read it carefully, sorry

Comment: This inserts an extra newline between each line and an extra newline at the end.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg What? No it doesn't

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yCS347pu

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge-93, 17 bytes

```
~:1+!#v_
>:#,_@>$
```

Nothing fancy here; just put everything on the stack, then pop it off.

Answer (score 4):

## Pure Bash (no external utilities), 56

```
mapfile a
for((i=${#a[@]};i--;));{
printf %s "${a[i]}"
}
```

This is one of the few answers to do exact `tac` emulation, as asked about in [Dennis' comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59239/implement-tac-print-lines-from-a-file-in-reverse/59274#comment142591_59239):

```
$ echo -en 'a\nb' | ./tacemu.sh | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 61 0a                                         ba.
$ echo -en 'a\nb\n' | ./tacemu.sh | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 0a 61 0a                                      b.a.
$
```

Comment: Nice and [inspiring](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59276).

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 16 bytes

```
puts [*$<].reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 16 bytes

```
print reverse<>
```

Comment: @Dennis oops, now reverted.

Answer (score 3):

### sed, 9 bytes

```
1!G;h;$!d
```

No upvote wanted, this is a famous sed one-liner.

Comment: If it's not your own work, I suggest making your answer community wiki.

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 41 bytes

```
$a=$args|%{gc $_};[array]::Reverse($a);$a
```

Stores the content of a file line by line in `a`, reverses `a` and finally prints it.

Answer (score 3):

## GolfScript, 7 bytes

```
n/-1%n*
```

Online test [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=J2FiYwpkZWYKZ2hpJwoKbi8tMSVuKgo%3D&run=true).

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](http://mroman.ch/burlesque/), 6 bytes

```
ln<-uN
```

`ln` splits lines, `<-` reverses, `uN` joins lines and formats for raw output.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>179</s> 171 bytes

```
using B=System.Console;class A{static void Main(){var a=new System.Collections.Stack();string b;while((b=B.ReadLine())!=null)a.Push(b);foreach(var c in a)B.WriteLine(c);}}
```

Reads lines, placing them in a stack, and then writes them backwards. I would use Mathematica for this, but it has no sense of EOF.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <s>48</s> 43 characters

(Inspired by [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)'s [Bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59275). Upvotes for the idea should go to him.)

```bash
mapfile -c1 -C's=$2$s;set'
printf %s "$2$s"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -en 'a\nb' | bash tac.sh | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 61 0a                                         ba.

bash-4.3$ echo -en 'a\nb\n' | bash tac.sh | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 0a 61 0a                                      b.a.
```

Comment: I think you can do `mapfile -c1 -Cf` instead of `mapfile -c1 -Cf a`.

Comment: Correct. I also discovered it in meantime, just tried something around that tricky `-C` first.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (SpiderMonkey Shell), 38 bytes

```
[...read(readline())].reverse().join``
```

Pretty simple

---

`read()` reads a file

`readline()` reads a string from STDIN

`[...str]` will split *str* into an array of chars

`reverse()` will reverse the array

``` join`` ``` will collpase the array into a string

Answer (score 3):

## GNU Awk, 27 characters

(Inspired by [Ed Morton](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45679/ed-morton)'s [GNU Awk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59322). CW as I not intended to hijack his solution.)

```awk
{s=$0RT s}END{printf"%s",s}
```

Note that by changing `RT` → `RS` this becomes portable standard Awk but looses the ability to preserve the absence of the final newline.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -en 'a\nb' | awk '{s=$0RT s}END{printf"%s",s}' | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 61 0a                                         ba.

bash-4.3$ echo -en 'a\nb\n' | awk '{s=$0RT s}END{printf"%s",s}' | xxd -g 1
0000000: 62 0a 61 0a                                      b.a.
```

Comment: You can remove the "%s"

Comment: @ninjalj, only if we can assume that the input will never contain “%”.

Answer (score 3):

## SNOBOL, 42 bytes

```
S S =INPUT CHAR(10) S :S(S)
 OUTPUT =S
END
```

Answer (score 2):

## Gema, 25 characters

```
*\n=@set{s;$0${s;}}
\Z=$s
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -en 'a\nb' | gema '*\n=@set{s;$0${s;}};\Z=$s'
ba

bash-4.3$ echo -en 'a\nb\n' | gema '*\n=@set{s;$0${s;}};\Z=$s'
b
a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), <strike>90 Bytes</strike> 86 Bytes

```
use IO;func main(){c=File.readLines(args[0]);for(x=c.length-1;x>=0; println(c[x--]))0;
```

See expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=0a2a15ed11c102ba90de2012c6078c09)

Comment: I you can shorten this a lot by abusing `for` syntax. See a sample [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=b66a81075442a66f5bfd398eebd5feb3)

Comment: Good call @FryAmTheEggman! I added it in.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript(Node.js), 91 Bytes

```
console.log(require('fs').readFileSync(process.argv[2])+"".split(d="\n").reverse().join(d))
```

Comment: Did you mean `console.log((require('fs').readFileSync(process.argv[2])+"").split(d="\n").reverse().join(d))` (92 bytes)? Your current code does not reverse the lines.

Answer (score 2):

## sed, 7 bytes

```
G;h;$!d
```

This works for me (and it's the shortest solution elsewhere), but I don't really want to find out why. I just messed around with the famous 9-byte trick until I found this. I guess `G`ing the first line does nothing?

Comment: Actually does something: your code produces an extra newline at the end of output. (`G` appends a newline and the content of hold space to the pattern space. While appending the content of empty hold space is indeed harmless, the newline is still appended.)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + common utilities, 25

```
tr \\n ^G|rev|tr ^G \\n|rev
```

Here the `^G` is a literal `BEL` character.  I'm assuming the input is only printable ascii.

This `tr`ansforms the entire input to one line by replacing newlines with BELs, then `rev`erses that line, then `tr`ansforms back to multiline, then `rev`erses each line again, to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 44

```
@(x) strjoin(fliplr(strsplit(x,'\n')),'\n');
```

Splits the string at new lines, flips the resulting array, then rejoins with new line characters.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 65 bytes

```julia
open(s->print(join(reverse([l for l=readlines(s)]),"")),ARGS[1])
```

This takes a file as a command line argument and prints its lines in reverse order. Trailing newlines are moved to the front, unlike `tac`, which is legit.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function p(s::Stream)
    # Create a vector of the lines of the input stream
    L = [l for l in readlines(s)]

    # Reverse the vector and join it back into a string
    j = join(reverse(L), "")

    # Print the string to STDOUT
    print(j)
end

# Open the file specified in the first command line argument
# and apply the function p to its contents
open(p, ARGS[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 + 2 = 5 bytes

Uses the `r` and `n` flags; reads from stdin.

```
RVg
```

The `r` flag reads stdin and stores it as a list of lines in `g` (which is normally a list of command-line ar**g**s). We then reverse that list, and it is auto-printed. The `n` flag causes lists to be output with newline as a separator.

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, 55 bytes

```
0i:1+?!v:a=?v}1+!
0.20r}~<    >~}00
oa]~~.?)2l2dor[;!?l
```

It first counts the length of each line so it can isolate them in a separate stack when it browses back the lines to display them.

It can probably get shorter, I may work on it later.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Ḋ;ƈ$ÐLỴṚY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wR5f1sQ6VwxN8Hu7e8nDnrMj//0MyMosVgCgnMy9VwVCPC4VfUp6vx@VZrFCSARMxtufyVEjJz1MvUShKTczJqVTIzssv11FIKi1R8FTQAirMy9aCqIdpMdEDAA)

Thanks to [Dennis](/users/12012) for -1.

Comment: Note: I assume that "provided as a name or via standard input" means that we can choose whether our program will take input from a file or STDIN (as other answers do), so, in this case, my program takes input from STDIN.

Answer (score 2):

## [Addict](https://github.com/ETHproductions/addict), 67 bytes

```
a g
 t _[_]
 p
 o
a p
 i _
 g
 d
a o
 d _
 s
 d
a s
 c _[_]
 o
 d
g
```

Copy and paste the code [here](https://github.com/ETHproductions/addict) to try it.

Answer (score 1):

### STATA, 46 bytes

```
inf str99 v using a.b
g a=-_n
so a
l v,noo noh
```

Expects input as a file called a.b, with each line no more than 99 characters. Reads in a file and labels the variable v. Makes a new variable called a with the negative index of it. Sort by the negative index (i.e. reverse order) and then list every thing in sorted (i.e. reverse) order.

For a longer length of lines, put quotes around each line and use (42 bytes):

```
insheet using a.b
g a=-_n
so a
l v,noo noh
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
(io.Source.stdin.getLines():\0){(a,b)=>println(a);0}
```

Bastardizing/side-effecting `foldRight` (`:\`) to deal with iterators (as returned by `getLines`) not having `reverse`

Answer (score 1):

## GNU command line environment, <strike>41</strike> <strike>40</strike> 37 bytes

```
cat -n|sort -nr|sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>80</strike> 72 bytes

It isn't the best solution, but I guess it's something.

```
a=lambda x: f=open(x,'r');l=f.readlines();for o in reversed(l): print(o)
```

Any tips on golfing it further?

Comment: `return` outside of a `def` function is a syntax error. If you use a lambda, the return value is the result of the (single) expression.

Comment: @NickT Thanks, I'll (try to) fix it.

Comment: would `l[::-1]` instead of `reversed(l)` work?
Also, you could remove the spaces after the `:`

Answer (score 1):

## q, 35 bytes

```
-1 each reverse read0 hsym`$.z.x 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 145 bytes

Not as short as I hoped.. But I tried!

### Golfed

```
using System.Linq;class c{static void Main(string[]a){foreach(var s in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(a[0]).Reverse())System.Console.WriteLine(s);}}
```

### Ungolfed

```
using System.Linq;
class c
{
    static void Main(string[]a)
    {
        foreach(var s in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(a[0]).Reverse())
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 6 bytes:

```
!Grev<cr>
```

Filters every line through the external command: `rev`. Must be run on linux.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@6/oXpRaxvX/v0dqTk4@V3l@UU4KAA)

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 52

File is named `F`

```
puts [join [lreverse [split [read [open F]] \n]] \n]
```

## [demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMejg1V21NRFdJaDg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
j_.z
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_.z&input=abc%0Adef&debug=0)

Takes input from STDIN

### explanation

```
j_.z
  .z    # Input as list of lines
 _      # reverse
j       # join on newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
¤r
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWlucHV0X2xpc3QlMjByZXZlcnNlJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9SGVsbG8lMkMlMjBXb3JsZCElMEFUaGlzJTIwaXMlMjBhJTIwbXVsdGlsaW5lJTIwc3RyaW5nJTJDJTBBYW5kJTIwdGhlJTIwbGluZXMlMjBhcmUlMjBnb2luZyUyMHRvJTIwZ2V0JTIwcmV2ZXJzZWQhJTBBR29vZGJ5ZSUyQyUyMGNydWVsJTIwd29ybGQuJmZsYWdzPXZO)

- `¤` - lines of input
- `r` - reverse
- `N` - join on newlines